# How to track mpeg ts i b p frames in a PCAP file through wireshark/dpkt

Tags: wireshark, pcap, mpeg

I am working through a PCAP file that consists of a single channel of MPEG TS packets carried over UDP in Wireshark and I had a few questions

1. What's the difference between the more numerous TS packets and the PES packets? The TS packets are far more numerous
2. Is there a way to analyze the payloads of the TS packets and extract the i b p frames from the data along with timestamps so that I could perhaps see their throughput?

Answer (score 0):

You can usually check for I frames by looking at the "random access indicator" bit. But it is possible for the muxer to set that incorrectly. For P and B frames; Its is codec dependent and each codec has a different process that requires parsing the codec bitstream.

Comment: Looking at wikipedia, the random access indicator bit means that "the stream may be decoded without errors from this point". I am confused as to how the bit being set indicates an I frame. And i guess as a further note, is there a way to group the ts packets together so that I could say that a set of the packets make up one video frame?

Comment: If you attempt to decode starting at a P or B frame, you will get errors. Don’t ask new questions in comments. New questions should get new posts.